# How to set NULL if one group doesn't match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this regex:

```
var match  = /^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/m.exec(val);
var before = Number(match[1]) + 1;
```

Now when there isn't any matched, I faced with this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

How can I fix it? I think I have to set `NULL` instead `match[1]`.

Comment: What do you want `before` to be when `match` is `null`?

Comment: Do you mean this instead `var match  = (/^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/).exec(val);` m.exec  won't work as it has not been defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`var before = ( match === null ) ? 1 : match[1]`

This will set `before` to `1` if there were no matches found, otherwise it should return the correct match.

Comment: I didnt know you could use those conditions in Javascript?

Comment: Which ones are you talking about? The ternary operator (`?`) is a standard part of Javascript.

Comment: The conditional `?:` operator is present in a lot of C-family/C-like languages (Java, C, C++, Javascript, C+, etc...)

Comment: @Purag Cool, im still learning javascript so this is new to me. I didnt know you could use ternary operators. Thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You should preform a match first to see if there is one.

```
var m = /^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/m.exec(val);
var before = m === null ? 0 : +m[1]+1;
/* notice the Array returned by match can be immediately accessed then
   cast to a number with + in front */
```

Comment: What arcane runes are these, o wizard?